# How get values from Thread on real time with JSP?

Tags: java, multithreading, jsp

First to nothing, sorry for my english.

I want get informacion from:

```
public class vCinco extends Thread {
    private Integer val = 0;
    public vCinco(){

    }
```

Function to get the actually value:

```
    public String getVal(){
        return String.valueOf(val);
    }

    public void run(){
        try{
            for (int i=10; i>0; i--) {
                val=i;
                System.out.println(val);
                Thread.sleep( 1000 );
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Using a JSP:

```
<body>
        <div>The apocalypse starts in...</div>
        <%
            vCinco t1 = new vCinco();
            t1.start();
            out.println(t1.getVal()); // Here I want that the number change on every change of the thread "t1" (vCinco)

        %>
</body>
```

How can I do that ??

Thankyou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First:**

Never and never run a thread implicitly from a servlet, or jsp, for sake of memory leak. running threads should be done via a manageable stuff at server like `ContextListener`s which help you avoid the memory leak and ...

**Second:**

Are you supposed to get the value live?! I mean something like a real counter in client side? so why not using a simple javascript?

Even if you insist to have the counter at server side, you need to have a live contact with the server either ajax calls or web-socket or old page refresh, and it doesn't need thread too.

Please state the business, if you need some action of user within 10 seconds, so you have set the timer at client via javascript, ALSO related info at server about the counter start time since the client-side stuffs are not reliable even 1%.

Comment: Well, I wanted this for learning purposes really. Because in a class of University, one of my teachers request to implement a Dekker's algorithms versions with animation and I can only create animation in html/javascript/CSS3. So I think maybe that was possible, but if that is a bad programming practice in something very simple better I won't do.

Comment: Running threads directly from jsp,servlet,.. are not recommended, because the thread will be under container process(not the servlet/jsp) so memory leak would get appeared. Besides your case study doesn't need any thread at the end.  just set the start time(timestamp) at server with user session, and call the/a servlet for getting the reminded time using ajax